# DFS and SMB(jcifs) Issue in java

Tags: java, windows, smb, jcifs, microsoft-distributed-file-system

We are trying to create directory on DFS Share using jcifs in java.

**DFS on server1**  : 
                     DOMAIN/Root/path1 from server1 smb store 
                     DOMAIN/Root/path2 from server2 smb store

while creating directory on  from **debug** mode on Eclipse.. using SMBFile in jcifs(Java),**directory created successfully** on that DFS Share.

But the same program **tried and executed as windows service,it is not working throws exception as "Smb Access Denied" Exception**.

Thanks in Adcvance...

Comment: you need run the service in domain user account instead of Local system account.

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your class path.

-Djcifs.smb.client.dfs.disabled="false".

It should work